# php date st, nd, rd, th

Tags: php

> Модификатор `S` в функции `date()` - Английский суффикс порядкового
>   числительного дня месяца, 2 символа `st`, `nd`, `rd` или `th`. Применяется
>   совместно с `j`

Дата выводится на русском. Кроме этого суффикса. Как перевести на русский? Или единственный вариант - это убирать даный модификатор из формата? Никакой информации найти не могу.

Comment: Используйте IntlDateFormatter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296390/formatting-date-ordinal-suffix-for-the-day-of-the-month из пакета intl (может надо установить).

Comment: вы хотите `ое, е, ее` получить? как то это, имхо, не особо литературно писать `18-е октября`. хз есть ли в этом смысл вообще. т.е. я бы сказал, что у нас таки это не особо принято. но если мультиязычный проект, то да. Хотя  настройки локалей должны быть для разных языков свои все равно. Оставьте на край везде суффикс `е` :D

Comment: а, или там `-ый, -ой, -ий`

Comment: Мультиязычный проект, именно. Иначе бы я не задался этим вопросом ) Я хочу получить отсутствие английского в русской дате. Без изменения кода проекта. Наклхозить так то можно что душе угодно.

Comment: `IntlDateFormatter` дает просто точку на конце, если я правильно понял.

Comment: дак а как вы дату пишите? в русском если это `дд.мм.гггг` а в США `mm-dd-yyyy` в англии `dd/mm/yyyy`, надо все равно форматировать в соответствие с локалью пользователя. И в русской локали такого суффикса обычно не бывает.